# ISO_3166-1 Country Names and java.util.Locale

Tags: java, iso

I am trying to convert an ISO-assigned country name to its ISO_3166-1 alpha 3 (3 letter) code. I have already seen code snippets here to that effect.

However, it seems there's a difference the string returned by `getDisplayCountry` method vs the *assigned name* shown on [the ISO website](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search/code/). For example, for the Alpha 3 code "RUS", the `getDisplayCountry` is `"Russia"` whereas the ISO assigned English name (aka English short name) is as shown below.

[image: iso website screenshot - RUS]

How do I work around this problem? Especially if I dont want to maintain a seperate lookup file - which defeats the whole point of using the built-in java class.

Comment: Why is it so important to use the name from the website?  The purpose of ISO 3166 is to define internationally recognised codes of letters and/or numbers that we can use when we refer to countries and subdivisions. However, it does not define the names of countries. https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html

Comment: You'd have to create your own `Locale`. My question would be that if one of your user sees "Russia" instead of "The Russian federation", what could be the confusion?

Comment: Hello and thanks for taking the time to respond. The incoming data will contain country names that are based on the ISO list - as shown on the website. The code I am referring to is not user-facing. It is part of an inbound interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Locale.getDisplayCountry()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayCountry--) returns the country name in a form that's appropriate to show to the user in their locale:

> Returns a name for the locale's country that is appropriate for display to the user. If possible, the name returned will be localized for the default DISPLAY locale. For example, if the locale is fr_FR and the default DISPLAY locale is en_US, getDisplayCountry() will return "France"; if the locale is en_US and the default DISPLAY locale is fr_FR, getDisplayCountry() will return "Etats-Unis". If the name returned cannot be localized for the default DISPLAY locale, (say, we don't have a Japanese name for Croatia), this function falls back on the English name, and uses the ISO code as a last-resort value. If the locale doesn't specify a country, this function returns the empty string.

The ISO website lists countries in both English and French variants only. It looks like Java may use a different (or altered) source of country names so these names are not guaranteed to match even for the en_US locale as you've noted.

If all you have to match on is the display name (and your display name is normalized throughout your dataset) you can create a map between lists. Essentially you'd download the ISO list and using the 2 or 3 digit country codes create a lookup table consisting of ISO display name to Java display name. From there you can map your data.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mike. In other words, you are saying that the value displayed on the ISO website might not necessarily be the value that Java returns. So, either do an additional lookup or use the java display values as source strings :-( I have reached the same conclusion, just making sure I am not missing a third alternative.

Comment: What a mess to have Russia instead of Russian Federation as the iso.org value is the second one. Is there any reason for not getting the official ISO Country Names? https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:RU
The Java Locale class follow the ISO pattern for the code but not for the country name... there is no sense on it.